# Prove (or disprove) a correlation between a prime number subset and a maximum $n\in\mathbb N_+$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

**EDIT:** Further expansion on the topic can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881937/if-p-is-a-finite-set-of-primes-such-that-sum-p-frac1p1-express-max).

---

I'm kind of testing my own observation that I came up with but may very well have already been worked on. I basically try to find a correlation between the following two:

Let $P = \{p\in\mathbb N_+ | p~$  is prime$\}$ be a non-empty finite set of different prime numbers. Is it true, that:
$${\displaystyle \sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p} > 1 \Longrightarrow \exists n_{max}\in\mathbb N_+:\sum_{p\in P}\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\rfloor} < n$$

(note that the existence of a **maximal** such $n$ is implied)

I also know for a fact (rather easy to prove) that if ${\displaystyle \sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p} \le 1}$, then the inequality on the right hand side holds for infinitely large $n$s, so the implication might as well be an equivalence! But I'm currently struggling with the general proofs.

I was inspired by a certain example with the set $P = \{2, 3, 11, 13\}$, which additionally satisfies the condition:
$${\displaystyle \sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}} = 1 + \prod_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}$$

so that might as well be a necessary condition for the implication to hold true. I've figured out the solution to this partial case to be $n = 1715$.

And generally I'm really interested in this correlation... Any intel on the topic is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: An [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuga_number) about your "additional" condition.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the article, it is indeed amazing! I'll see if I can find an application for it in this case. (Sorry for the inconveniece with the previous comments, the edit of the post turned out quite cardinal...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sum_P(1/p)=1+\delta$ for some $\delta>0$, and let $m$ be the number of elements of $P$. $$\sum_P[n/p]>\sum_P((n/p)-1)=n(1+\delta)-m=n+(n\delta-m)>n$$ for $n>m/\delta$.

Comment: Lovely, just lovely! Exactly what I was missing. I thank you very much!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this should work the other way around as well... So we can say that the statement is indeed an equivalence rather than an implication, right?

Comment: You've written that the implication in the other direction is easy to prove. If that's so, then, yes, it's an equivalence. Indeed, for the "other way around", just take $n$ to be any multiple of all the primes in $P$.

Comment: Brilliant! I have, indeed, stated the same thing but just hadn't realised it... Thank you a lot for the clarification!

Comment: If my answer settles the question for you, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: It actually does, regarding the initial question, but I just don't want to close the thread yet since I'm also interested in computing the exact maximal $n$ and wanted to edit and extend my original post. Or maybe I should create a new thread?

Comment: Once you get an answer, it's considered impolite to change the question. You're supposed to decide what you want to ask before you post the question, not some time afterwards.

Comment: Wait, I think that's not quite it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think proving that this inequality holds vor all $n > m/\delta$ does not necessarily imply that there are finitely many $n$ for which it does not hold... since it may (and most often does) hold for all $n$.

Comment: ?? If it holds for all $n>m/\delta$ then it can only fail to hold for $n<m/\delta$, and there are only finitely many positive integers $n$ that are less than $m/\delta$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I caused any inconvenience, didn't mean to offend you. I just thought that it would be better to extens the topic to its full potential in a single thread... You know, questions come afterwards as well, the research evolves, so to speak. So I just wanted to leave some more room for conversation. :) Otherwise people would tend to ignore the thread as "completed".

Comment: This website isn't for conversations. It's for focussed questions with well-defined answers. If you have another question, post another question. (But if it's closely related to this question, then put a link to each question at the other one).

Comment: Yes, finitely many, but not necessarily **any**, since it can also fail for none of them (which is 0 on count, also finite, but not what we want).

Comment: Most people consider zero to be finite. If you want to rule out zero, that should be (or should have been) stated in the question. No matter; zero can't happen, since the inequality always holds for $n=1$.

Comment: You are right, I got confused again... It's getting late here. Thank you again for your help and thorough explanations! I will open up another thread regarding the expression of the exact $n_{max} $ in terms of $P$!