# If $P$ is a finite set of primes, such that $\sum_P\frac{1}{p}>1$, express $max\{n\in\mathbb N_+ : \sum_P\Big\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor<n\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

**EDIT:** Further expansion on the topic can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899671/relation-between-a-set-of-primes-the-giuga-numbers-and-a-maximum-of-a-natural-n).

---

As discussed here: [Prove (or disprove) a correlation between a prime number subset and a maximum $n\in\mathbb N_+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881082/prove-or-disprove-a-correlation-between-a-prime-number-subset-and-a-maximum-n), it is true that
$$\sum_{P}\frac{1}{p} > 1 \Longleftrightarrow 0 < \#\{n\in\mathbb N_+: \sum_{P}\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor < n\} < \infty$$

In other words, if $P$ is a non-empty **finite** prime numbers subset with the property ${\displaystyle \sum_{P}\frac{1}{p} > 1}$, then the set $N_P := \bigg\{n\in\mathbb N_+~:~ {\displaystyle\sum_{P}}\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor < n\bigg\}$ is finite and therefore contains a maximum element $maxN_P$. My question would be, is it possible to always express $maxN_P$ in terms of $P$ and what would be the corresponding representation?

I've got a suggestion but can't really finish my proof in a rigorous manner. Prepare for a longer read...

Assuming the condition, let's take a look at the definition of our set $N_P$ and more precisely at the left hand side of the defining inequality.

Initial note: $\forall n, m\in\mathbb N_+: \Big\lfloor \frac{n}{m} \Big\rfloor = \frac{n - (n\bmod m)}{m} \in \mathbb N_+$

So the left hand side is equivalent to:

$$\sum_{p\in P} \Big\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \Big\rfloor = \sum_{p\in P} \frac{n - (n\bmod p)}{p} = \bigg(n\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}\bigg) - \sum_{p\in P}\frac{n\bmod p}{p}$$

Thus the defining inequality becomes:
$$\bigg(n\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}\bigg) - \sum_{p\in P}\frac{n\bmod p}{p} < n$$
$$\Updownarrow$$
$$- \sum_{p\in P}\frac{n\bmod p}{p} < n\bigg(1 - \sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}\bigg)$$

But since ${\displaystyle \sum_P\frac{1}{p}} > 1$, we can define a real number $\delta := {\displaystyle \bigg(\sum_P\frac{1}{p}}\bigg) - 1 > 0$ and the inequality is equivalent to:
$$\sum_{p\in P}\frac{n\bmod p}{p} > \delta n$$

It is quite obvious that the left hand side is an upper bounded function of $P$ and $n$, so let's define it:
$$f_P(n) := \sum_{p\in P}\frac{n\bmod p}{p}$$

So we've narrowed down the defining inequality to:
$$\boxed{f_P(n) > \delta n \Longleftrightarrow n < \frac{f_P(n)}{\delta}}$$

Obviously $f_P(n)$ reaches its maximum value for such $n$s that satisfy the condition: $\forall p\in P: n\equiv -1 ~(\bmod ~p) \Longleftrightarrow n = k\bigg({\displaystyle \prod_{p\in P}p}\bigg) - 1$ for some $k\in\mathbb N_+$

Thus ${\displaystyle f_{P_{max}} = \sum_{p\in P}\frac{p - 1}{p} = |P| - \sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}} = |P| -1 - \delta$

**DRUMS** And here comes the part where I'm stuck. I'd suppose by intuition that the $n_{max} := maxN_P$ we're searching is the biggest natural number that:

- is namely of the form $n = k\bigg({\displaystyle \prod_{p\in P}p}\bigg) - 1$, since then $f_P(n)$ will be at its max for the predefined set $P$; and
- also satisfies $n < \frac{f_P(n)}{\delta} = \frac{f_{P_{max}}}{\delta} = \frac{|P| - 1}{\delta} - 1 \Longleftrightarrow n < \frac{|P| - 1}{\delta} - 1$

Combining both the conditions above allows for a closed and really satisfying expression of $n$ in terms of $P$ alone, which is the goal. Let's call this candidate for an answer $n_s$ ($s$ stands for 'supposed' :D)

**CRITICAL POINT** But as you can see, the main problem is proving that the maximum number satisfying both the conditions above (i.e. $n_s$) is indeed the maximum number that satisfies the defining inequality (i.e. $n_{max} = n_s$)...

In other words, can we be sure that there are no bigger natural numbers than $n_s$ that won't be of the form $n = k\bigg({\displaystyle \prod_{p\in P}p}\bigg) - 1$, but will still satisfy $n < \frac{f_P(n)}{\delta}$? Mathematically written: can we (dis)prove, that:
$$\big(\not\exists n\in N_P : n > n_s\big) \Longleftrightarrow n_s = maxN_P$$

What are your thoughts? Any help on the topic would be greatly appreaciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can hope for a general formula. E.g. for $P = \{2,3,7,11\}$ we have $n_{\text{max}} = 20$ (not to mention $n_{\text{max}} = 5$ for $P = \{2,3,5,7\}$). But I think that *if* $P$ is such that $\delta^{-1} = m = \prod_{p \in P} p$, then $n_{\text{max}} = \bigl(\lvert P\rvert - 2\bigr)\cdot m - 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You have a very clear point I've missed before about the case when $\prod_{p\in P}p > \delta^{-1}(|P| - 1)$, since any single example of such sort automatically disproves my suggestion... Poor $n_s$ isn't our answer! :D The whole question was posed as an observation of mine, so it could also not work. You've proven such a case exists. So the initial conditions are open for updates, if we're able to prove the existence of a closed formula for given cireterias for $P$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I will take a look at your suggestion, which quite reminds me of the Giuga numbers, mentioned in a comment on the previous post. The example set $P = \{2, 3, 11, 13\}$ satisfies namely that condition.