# Relation between a set of primes, the Giuga numbers and a maximum of a natural numbers set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

I didn't really know how to put it better in the title, so I'm open for better formulations.

**1. First off, some insight on Giuga numbers:**

A [Giuga number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuga_number) is a natural number $G_P\in\mathbb N_+$, the set $P$ of whose distinct prime factors fulfills the condition: $\forall p\in P: p|(\frac{G_P}{p}-1)$. Hence, Giuga numbers are [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) and **not** [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime), meaning they're a product of at least 3 distinct primes to the first power. In other words, as I understand it, a Giuga number is defined by a specific unique finite set of at least 3 primes

$P = \Big\{p$ prime$ ~:~ (p+1)|{\displaystyle \prod_{q\in P\setminus\{p\}}}q\Big\}$ as $G_P = {\displaystyle \prod_{p\in P}p}$

Furthermore, every known Giuga number thus far also satisfies the stronger condition ${\displaystyle\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p} - \prod_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}} = 1$, which is strongly correlated to the question I'm about to pose.

**2. Previous research**

- From the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881082/prove-or-disprove-a-correlation-between-a-prime-number-subset-and-a-maximum-n) we concluded that for every non-empty finite set of distinct primes $P$ the following is true: $$\sum_{P}\frac{1}{p} > 1 \Longleftrightarrow 0 < \#\{n\in\mathbb N_+: \sum_{P}\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor < n\} < \infty$$
  (where $\#A = |A| = $ the count of the elements in $A$)
- In the follow-up discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881937/if-p-is-a-finite-set-of-primes-such-that-sum-p-frac1p1-express-max) I tried to come up with an expression for $maxN_P$, where $N_P = \{n\in\mathbb N_+: \sum_{P}\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor < n\}$ is the set of natural numbers with the property regarding $P$ defined above. From that same discussion and some mere previous observations of mine (and finally after a confirming push in the right direction from @**Daniel Fischer**'s comment) arose my next question:

**3. The question itself**

Let $P$ be a non-empty finite prime numbers set with the property ${\displaystyle\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p} - \prod_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}} = 1$ and $N_P = {\displaystyle\{n\in\mathbb N_+: \sum_{P}\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\Big\rfloor < n\}}$.

Is it true and can we prove, that $maxN_P = {\displaystyle\bigg((|P| - 2)\prod_{p\in P}p\bigg) - 1}$?

Important to notice is that we're now focusing on that stronger condition for the set $P$ and already have a conjectured candidate for our closed expression of $maxN_P$, which really makes it beautiful in my opinion.

I prefer not to share my further progress yet in order not to influence your fresh ideas and not to make the post too long... (but if you're interested, I'll be glad to do it; as for starters, you can read my initial progress in the [second post I referenced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881937/if-p-is-a-finite-set-of-primes-such-that-sum-p-frac1p1-express-max))

**4. The relation to Giuga's numbers**

As you might've recognized, ${\displaystyle \prod_{p\in P}p}$ is exactly the Giuga number $G_P$ defined by the set $P$. In other words, what we're trying to prove is equivalent to $$G_P = \frac{maxN_P + 1}{|P| - 2}$$

This has proven to be true for most of the known Giuga numbers discovered so far (all I could test against, at least) and I have a really strong intuition that it's generally true, but have just not managed to finish any version of a rigorous proof for it.

which I think would be a nice little fact about Giuga numbers (provided that they all satisfy the stronger condition mentioned in the beginning). That would actually even be an alternative way to define the $(|P| - 2)$-th Giuga number, which would namely equal $maxN_P + 1$. So I've grown really keen on this sweet correlation and would really love to gather some new intel on it.

I'm open for new ideas and would really be happy about any shared opinions on the topic! Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is very interesting ! (+1)